# cache.ini file - require to clear

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, cache

Using SharePoint 2013 and experiencing an issue with resetting Search index and found a few articles that explain how to clear the cache.

In the APP Server, 6 GUID folders exist 3 of which contain a `cache.ini` file.

[image: APP SERVER]

In the WFE 4 Guid Folders exist 2 which contain cache.ini

[image: WFE SERVER]

So not sure which folder(s) I should be looking at. Maybe the modified date is something to go by?

I checked [SharePoint 2010 – Clearing the Configuration Cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jamesway/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right, the folder having current modified date has the cache.ini folders.

As per pictures from both servers, you open 25/05/2017's folder.

Leave other folders as is.

Comment: Can the other folders be deleted? Are these folders created every time the config wizard runs?

Comment: I won't delete them, as these were created by SharePoint. I have couple of folders on each of my servers.

Comment: Looks all good. 
The WFE chace.ini has number 5929763 , and App has 5929755

Comment: this is normal, it is little different between the servers.